# Overriding package.json keys while running npm script command

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron application.

My package.json has some app-specific settings like `serverUrl`, `type_of_application` etc. I am using these settings in the application.

When building an application with `electron-builder` I want to override these configs key values with different values.

I will be building same application with different `serverUrl` for different `type_of_application`. Also there is possibility that these will be installed on same machine so I also want to change package `name` and `productName` key values for different builds.

So my target is to have separate config files with all these settings to build application with different settings. And when building I will use one of the the config file and that should override default configs in `package.json` file.

One possibility is to have complete package.json for different kind of builds, but in that case `dependencies` etc. keys will also be duplicated which will be hard to manage when a new dependency is added.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: One option may be to insert the volatile metadata in the build process with the `extraMetadata` electron-builder option. If you start the build programmatically (javascript) instead of using the command line you could work dynamically with different configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy would be to keep all app specific configuration in one or more separate config files which your app loads on startup.

I tend to keep such files under `APP_HOMEDIR/etc` (a nod to my Unix roots), named for each app environment you require.

### Update

For Electron app development using `electron-builder`, a configuration key exists `extraMetadata` that allows you to inject values set in your `package.json` per build.

See [electron-builder configuration](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration) for further info.

(Thanks to the OP [Harshveer Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893039/harshveer-singh) for suggesting this update.)

Comment: This will apply after application is installed, right? I need to have different configurations and application using one of them. So that I can quickly build with different settings(without manually updating `package.json`), using something like: `npm build use-config1.json`

Comment: Then you might wish to use a build tool, like Gulp, to manage building for different runtime configurations.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way. For Electron app building, I found a build configuration key `extraMetadata` which overrides keys defined in `package.json`, so for for my case I am using that. If you can modify your response to answer build time configuration, I will accept that.

Comment: @HarshveerSingh How does `extraMetadata` work exactly? The docs don't explain it at all.